in ubuntu 24.04 super button stopped working
in Ubuntu 24.04 super + d which hides all windows is not working, i guess super button is not working, my laptop is asus and super button worked in Ubuntu 22.04, after update it stopped working is there any way to fix it?

@David I don't see this as a bug - see my answer.

The default for this option is Ctrl+Super+D However, if you reset it in your earlier versions it may well be that during the upgrade, the key combination was lost in the process.
The way to restore this is to go to Settings > Keyboard > View and Customise Shortcuts. In the search box enter  hide all windows or just select Navigation and the first option is Hide all normal windows.
If this is not set, then click on it and Set Shortcut by pressing whichever key combination you prefer. If it is set, you will see what combination is already set and then change it to your own preference.

